# How to dynamically construct query output variables in Coldfusion?

Tags: variables, dynamic, coldfusion, output

I'm trying to loop over an array which contains column names I need to display. A user can define his own columns, so this will be a dynamic column name list

For example, column names may be:

```
["style", "color", "size"]
```

These are the column names I need to output from my query called `results`.

I'm doing this:

```
<cfset variables.styleText = "">
<cfloop array="#DeserializeJSON(variables.raw.field_names)#" index="x">
   <cfset variables.styleText = variables.styleText & "#results." & x &"# ">
</cfloop>
<cfoutout>variables.styleText</cfoutput>
```

But this gives me an error, because I cannot end a variable name with a `quot` aka

```
 Diagnose: A CFML variable name cannot end with a &quot;.&quot; character. 
 The variable results. ends with a &quot;.&quot; character.  
 You must supply an additional structure key or delete the &quot;.&quot; character.
```

**Question:**
Can anyone give me a hint, how I need to modify this to output the values from my `results` query, in this case
`#results.style# #results.color# #results.size#`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
<cfloop array="#DeserializeJSON(variables.raw.field_names)#" index="x">
 <cfset variables.styleText = variables.styleText & "#results." & x &"# ">
</cfloop>
```

You should be able to do

```
<cfloop array="#DeserializeJSON(variables.raw.field_names)#" index="x">
 <cfset variables.styleText = variables.styleText & results[x][results.currentrow]>
</cfloop>
```

Or if you're using CF9 or higher simply

```
<cfset variables.styleText&=results[x][results.currentrow]>
```

Comment: Ok. Trying. Thanks. Using `CF8` though, so I'm going with your first suggestions

Comment: Cool. Works. Thank you very much!